# DefaultWorkforceTimesheetService returns unmodifiable list

Tags: java, s4sdk

With SDK version 2.4.2 the DefaultWorkforceTimesheetService returns an unmodifiable List when calling method getAllTimeSheetEntry(). This makes all further actions on the list impossible (sorting, removal of unneeded entries).
With version 2.3.1 the returned list is modifiable.
Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Version 2.7.0 has been released and should fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an intended change. The next release of the SDK should contain a fix. Thanks for noticing!

**Update: Version 2.7.0 has been released and should fix this issue.**